# Can’t run Quartz Example 4

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I try to pass parameters to my job class. I found [this example](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/generated/2.2.1/html/qs-all/Quartz_Scheduler_Documentation_Set/re-exp_example4.html#wwconnect_header), not really good; I think it is helpful, but, some step are not explained.
They have written lines not in the right order (especially for the job class) and they have created two time the variable "data" (!!?).
Maybe, it is understood that I have to organize and complete the details by myself.

...but the question was not really here, I have paste the example, complete it and run it, then, an error occurred.

Firstly, this message:

```
79 [MyScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] ERROR org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger  - An error occured instantiating job to be executed. job= 'group1.job'
```

then, a bigger, but maybe caused by this first message.

other question, why the console give me this message:

```
 [MyScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread  - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
```

Have you run this example successfully?

EDIT: I had suppressed all the program, so I write it now and I think it was this error:

```
[MyScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] ERROR org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger  - An error occured instantiating job to be executed. job= 'group1.job1'
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Problem instantiating class 'com.searchengine.lms.admin.jdbc.MysqlJob' -  [See nested exception: java.lang.NullPointerException]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.initialize(JobRunShell.java:134)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:375)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.quartz.simpl.PropertySettingJobFactory.setBeanProps(PropertySettingJobFactory.java:98)
    at org.quartz.simpl.PropertySettingJobFactory.newJob(PropertySettingJobFactory.java:76)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.initialize(JobRunShell.java:127)
    ... 1 more
69   [MyScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] INFO  org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore  - All triggers of Job group1.job1 set to ERROR state.
69   [MyScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread  - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
```

EDIT:

```
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.newJob;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.newTrigger;
import static org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule;

import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.SchedulerFactory;
import org.quartz.SimpleTrigger;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

public class MysqlScheduler{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SchedulerException, InterruptedException{

        //Voir les examples proposés par quartz-scheduler.org notamment sur les job parameters et job state
        SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler();

        JobDetail job1 = newJob(MysqlJob.class)
                .withIdentity("job1", "group1")
                .build();

            SimpleTrigger trigger1 = newTrigger() 
                .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
                        .withIntervalInSeconds(10)
                        .withRepeatCount(4))
                .build();
//          job1.getJobDataMap().put(MysqlJob.FAVORITE_COLOR, "Green");
//          job1.getJobDataMap().put(MysqlJob.EXECUTION_COUNT, 1);
//          sched.scheduleJob(job1, trigger1);
            sched.start();
            Thread.sleep(60L * 1000L);
            sched.shutdown(true);
    }
}
```

And

```
import org.quartz.DisallowConcurrentExecution;
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
import org.quartz.PersistJobDataAfterExecution;

@PersistJobDataAfterExecution
@DisallowConcurrentExecution 
public class MysqlJob implements Job{   

//  static final String FAVORITE_COLOR = null;
//  static final String EXECUTION_COUNT = null;
//  int counter = 1;
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        //Ici placer les tâches à effectuer
        System.out.println("A");
//      JobDataMap data = context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
//      int count = data.getInt(EXECUTION_COUNT);
//      count++;
//      data.put(EXECUTION_COUNT, count);



    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full message (the important info is the "bigger" one)

Comment: maybe you can give us some code to check?

Comment: Ok, but I just followed the example, so the code has’nt changed